# Second eigenvector of double eigenvalue matrix

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

$\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{2}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$

$\lambda_{1} = \lambda_{2} = -1$

The first vector is:

$v_{1} = \begin{bmatrix}x \\ x\end{bmatrix}$

$v_{1} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$

How can I calculate the second eigenvector? Because if I do something like this I have problem and can calculate any value for the vector.

$\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{2}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$

Can somebody help?

Answer (score 2):

Your matrix, as it is written, is singular: it must be that zero is one of its eigenvalues. In fact, only zero is an eigenvalue of algebraic order two, and the homogeneous system to obtain its eigenspace is

$$-\frac12x+\frac12y=0\implies x=y\implies V_{\lambda=0}=Span\left\{\binom11\right\}$$

and it's dimension is one, thus there is no other eigenvector linearly independent on the above one.

Comment: Yes but i dont need independent vector. I have to calculate matrix:

$e^{at} = Pe^{Jt}P^{-1}$ and i have all beside $P$ matrix and $P^{-1}$ So i have one vector but the other will be which?

Comment: The matrix which i wrote i after decrese it by eigenvalues. The main matrix is:

$A = \begin{bmatrix} -\frac{1}{2} & - \frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{1}{2} & - \frac{3}{2} \end{bmatrix}$

Comment: You have to find the Jordan normal form of the matrix for that.

Comment: @Hadson You wrote "how to calculate second eigenvector", but there is none (which is lin. ind. of the one already given). Perhaps you meant generalized eigenvector and you have to construct the matrix's Jordan Form.

Comment: Jordan form normal for matrix A is:

$J = \begin{bmatrix} -1 & 1 \\ 0 & -1\end{bmatrix}$ isnt it?

The $e^{Jt}$ is easy calculate to, but i have problem to get the second vector to matrix $P$ can you help? In your opinion how matrix $P$ will look like in this case?

Comment: @Hadson That's impossible as the only eigenvalue of your matrix is zero. You can also check your matrix has trace zero (as it must since it is a nilpotent matrix), whereas what you say is its Jordan Form has trace -2. That's impossible.

Comment: Ok, can you explain why wolfram show otherwise?
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i={{-1%2F2,-1%2F2},{1%2F2,+-3%2F2}}

Comment: @Hadson I don't know, but can't you see it is impossible your matrix is similar to the one you say it is? they have both trace and determinant different, and that just can't be? I think WA may have bugs.

Comment: I understand but i was little confuse because i got this one example on my exam and i stuck. Is possible that the teacher make mistake or sth?

Comment: @Hadson I don't know, but knowing your matrix is nilpotent non-zero makes it very easy to find its Jodan form: it is simply $$\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: @Joanpemo The OP didn’t give us the original matrix $A$ in his question. He’s given us $A-\lambda I$ which, of course, is singular.

Comment: @amd I don't know how you know this, as in the question I can't see any $\;\lambda\;$ in that matrix.

Comment: @Joanpemo The OP told us that he’s trying to find eigenvectors, has given an equation of the form $B\mathbf x=0$ to do this and told us that the eigenvalue is $-1$. It’s not a great deductive leap to infer from that and this discussion that the matrix in that equation isn’t the original but is $A-\lambda I=A+I$.

Answer (score 1):

To find the generalised eigenvector you simply have to solve for
$$\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{2}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$$
If $A$ is your given matrix, this indeed means a solution $e_2$ satisfies
$$(A+I)e_2=e_1,\quad\text{whence}\quad A e_2=-e_2+e_1.$$